Why is 面倒 Ateji and not just Onyomi?
According to the wiktionary page, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9D%A2%E5%80%92#Japanese, 面倒 is ateji and not just regular onyomi, when they use the on readings.

Roughly speaking, ateji is when characters are primarily chosen for their sounds (usually on'yomi) rather than their meanings. 面 and 倒 were chosen because of their readings (men and tou) rather than their meanings ("face" and "topple"), and so 面倒 is a prototypical example of ateji.

I don’t think that Wiktionary entry is clear. It needs to provide an etymology section which shows that the word isn’t derived from some kind of semantic extension of face + collapse before calling it ateji.

@dROOOze https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%9D%A2%E5%80%92/, citing デジタル大辞泉, argues that 面倒 is ateji (see under "[補説]").

Yes, if an etymology section was present which explains it as 「目 (め) どうな」の音変化, it would be clearer as to why it was ateji. It'd be nice to verify this, of course.

For those who can read Japanese, see also the 面倒の語誌 section in the 日本国語大辞典【にほんほくごだいじてん】 entry at Kotobank. That clearly lays out a case for this being a phonetic shift from 目【め】だう, where だう was a -na adjective suffix used in the Muromachi period to express senses of "useless, pointless, senseless waste [of something / to do something]", giving other examples like 「矢だうな」、「手間だうな」、「暇だうな」.

Apparently だう（な） is from older だく（な） via the kind of semi-regular "K" elision that changed classical よき into modern よい, and the resulting だう（な） then evolved into modern どう（な）.

On'yomi and ateji are not mutually exclusive concepts. In the case of 面倒, it's an ateji that utilizes on'yomi.

On'yomi means the reading originated from old Chinese. For 面, its on'yomi is めん and kun'yomi is つら. For 倒, its on'yomi is とう/どう and its kun'yomi is たお(れる).
Ateji means the kanji's reading was employed without respecting its meaning. For 面倒, its etymology actually has nothing to do with the meanings of 面 ("face") or 倒 ("collapse").

デジタル大辞泉 explains the etymology of 面倒 as follows:

「目どうな」の音変化。「どうな」は、むだになることで、見るだけむだなものが原義。「な」が形容動詞連体形語尾の「な」のように意識され、「めどう」「めんどう」となり、「面倒」と当て字されるようになった。

So めんどう is etymologically from me + dōna, where me means "eye" and dōna is an obsolete word that means "becoming futile". As na in dōna happened to look like the attributive ending of na-adjectives, it was back-formed as medō-na. Then it evolved into mendō-na, and the kanji 面倒 was finally assigned to the mendō part as ateji.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
